# Execution order of code in Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

In Spark Streaming
**val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost",1234)**
 line will create a DStream(collections of Rdd's) but I am confused that as there is always a sequential execution of code that is line by line,then how the above line of code will keep on generating DStream. 
And after this when an transformation is applied "**val words = lines.print()**"
how this line is printing all the data present in a given Rdd as this **val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost",1234)** is already in running mode.
Is in this process infinite looping is performed?
Please tell me the flow of Spark Streaming process
Thanks

Comment: If you want a deep dive in code where job scheduling takes place (at some batch interval) look here: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/scheduler/JobScheduler.scala#L66

Answer (score 1):

Spark's transformations are lazy. It means that nothing will be invoked before ana action will be called.

What it means for you?

1. `val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost",1234)` creates one DStream. Nothing is now read, just DStream is created with configuration from what source data will be read in future.
2. On `val words = lines.print()` you're declaring that every RDD created by first point will be printed. `words` variable is now composed of 2 declarations: source of data (point 1) and first action that will be invoked (print()).
3. Execution starts on `ssc.start()`. Spark then creates all necessary background classes, etc. - nothing you must know now :) Important thing is that Spark Context knows about every RDD created with this context. This StreamingContext has information about words DStream and after `ssc.start()` Spark will read data from source and then pass them into `print()` function.

In other words - you are not invoking actions/transformations that you're typing. You are just *declaring* that you want them to be invoked. It is something very similar to execution plan in SQL engine. Spark Context will execute actions and transformation that you want after `start()` is called and after each RDD from DStream is created by Spark. DStreams are created by Spark in some loop, but this is transparent for you